# Can't import ctypes from Blender's Python

Tags: python, windows

I'm having trouble importing the `ctypes` Python module from a 32-bit installation of Blender 2.73 on Windows. I need to use Blender's included Python, **not** the system Python. From the interactive console inside the Blender GUI with no project or anything loaded, I get the following error:

```
>>> import ctypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.73\python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

My Windows installation is 64-bit but I figured that shouldn't matter given that I'm running Python from a 32-bit installation of Blender and `ctypes` is part of the initial installation.

I have a feeling that the issue is specific to Windows because I cannot reproduce the issue on 64-bit Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Comment: try adding Blender's python to the %PATH% environment variable.it should be the first path so that blender doesn't use any other python you already have installed on your system.

Comment: @Houssem Thanks for the suggestion but I get the same error. I should note that I was getting this error even before I had installed a system Python for Windows at all, so I think the system Python interfering with Blender's Python is not likely the issue.

Comment: @zeffii This will be part of a larger, cross-platform project though, and it's been specified to run on 32-bit Blender, unfortunately.

Comment: @zeffii In general, 32-bit programs work fine on a 64-bit OS. I specifically installed the 32-bit version of Blender. I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in 2.73 and 2.73a:

https://developer.blender.org/T43961

Blender 2.74, 2.75 and 2.76 should work. adding the missing _ctypes python module (_ctypes.pyd) from these versions to 2.73 should also work.

Comment: I copied _ctypes.pyd from Blender 2.75a and simply replaced the existing file in 2.73a and it now works perfectly. Thanks so much for your help!